# How can I extract all monomials (without coefficients!) from a polynomial in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica provides MonomialList[f] to get all monomials in f:

```
MonomialList[(x+y)^2]={x^2,2xy,y^2}
```

But what I need is {x^2,xy,y^2}, how can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Inner[#2^#1 &, First/@CoefficientRules[#1, #2], #2, Times] &[(x + y)^2, {x, y}]
(*
{x^2, x y, y^2}
*)
```

Comment: Thx! A more general extension:`Inner[#2^#1 &, First/@CoefficientRules[#1, #2], #2, Times] &[f, Variables[f]]`

Comment: @Neo That one  won't work for polynomials with symbolic coefficients :)

Comment: I've noticed that. Thanks :)